# How to emphasize "I would rather"

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, expression-choice

I would like to emphasize the expression "I would rather... than ...".

My native language is French, and in French we would say something like "I would rather 1000 times.... than", so I'm looking for an equivalent in English.

Thank you

Comment: _than_ what? Please complete the phrase you are trying to emphasize...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to add emphasis to this construction is with "much" or "so"
"I would much rather fly than drive." 
"I would so rather rent than own."

Degrees of emphasis can be added, thus:
"I would so much rather the vaccine than the flu."
"I would far rather have a pool than a tennis court."
"I would infinitely rather dine alone than with you."

It may seem to be a class of vague quantity adverbs that function in this construction, but it is not every such adverb that is compatible, idiomatically, with rather.

For example, these do not work:

NO: "I would greatly rather a dog than a cat."
NO: "I would a lot rather watch than participate."

Comment: Can we say *I'd definitely/certainly rather*"?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin No, these won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would think of something appropriate, For example,

"I'd rather eat raw goats intestine than your mothers cooking"

or add as much emphasis as the situation requires

"I'd rather cut my testicles off with a blunt spoon than be seen driving a red car."

Just tone it down or up depending on the situation and the reaction you want.